# How can I pass user input from a what-if parameter to be used in a calculation in a measure?

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI so please bear with me, I've searched extensively for a solution but haven't been able to find quite the right thing.

I have a data set that contains (among other things) transactions with amounts and financial periods stored as whole numbers, and what I need to do is use those to arrive at YTD totals. So the user would select a period from 1-12 and then the YTD measure should calculate the totals for the selected period PLUS the previous periods (said another way, it should filter OUT the periods greater than the selected period).

I've tried to filter the totals for the appropriate periods by referencing the selected value of the parameter using "<=" but haven't been able to make that work:

```
ytd = CALCULATE(SUM(data_tbl[Calculated USD]),data_tbl[PERIOD NUMBER]<=current_period[current_period Value])
```

I'm probably approaching this the wrong way, but somehow I need to calculate YTD based on the user selecting the desired period. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It would help if you have an example of what your data looks like and what measures you are using or have tried to use for YTD.

Comment: Sure, so lets say the data has a column describing a transaction, a column for the amount, and a column for which period it's from (1-12). The measure I'm trying to use looks like this:   ytd = CALCULATE(SUM(data_tbl[Calculated USD]),data_tbl[PERIOD NUMBER]<=current_period[current_period Value])